# Use scale_x_continuous with labeller function that also takes a data frame as an argument as well as default breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's a code block:

```
# scale the log of price per group (cut)
my_diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  mutate(log_price = log(price)) %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(scaled_log_price = scale(log_price) %>% as.numeric) %>% # scale within each group as opposed to overall
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(mean_log_price = map_dbl(data, ~ .x$log_price %>% mean)) %>% 
  mutate(sd_log_price = map_dbl(data, ~ .x$log_price %>% sd)) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  select(cut, price, price_scaled:sd_log_price) %>% 
  ungroup


# for each cut, find the back transformed actual values (exp) of each unit of zscore between -3:3
for (i in -3:3) {
    my_diamonds <- my_diamonds %>%
      mutate(!! paste0('mean_', ifelse(i < 0 , 'less_', 'plus_'), abs(i), 'z') := map2(.x = mean_log_price, .y = sd_log_price, ~ (.x + (i * .y)) %>% exp) %>% unlist)
}

my_diamonds_split <- my_diamonds %>% group_split(cut)
split_names <- my_diamonds %>% mutate(cut = as.character(cut)) %>% group_keys(cut) %>% pull(cut)
names(my_diamonds_split) <- split_names
```

I now have a variable `my_diamonds_split` that is a list of data frames. I would like to loop over these data frames and each time create a new ggplot.

I can use a custom labeller function with a single df, but I don't know how to do this within a loop:

```
labeller <- function(x) {
  paste0(x,"\n",  scales::dollar(sd(ex_df$price) * x + mean(ex_df$price)))
}

ex_df <- my_diamonds_split$Ideal
ex_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = scaled_log_price)) +
  geom_density() +
  scale_x_continuous(label = labeller, limits = c(-3, 3))
```

This creates a plot for the 'Ideal' cut of diamonds. I also get two data points on the x axis, the zscore values at -2, 0 and 2 as well as the raw dollar values of 3.8K, 3.9K and 11.8K.

[image]

When I define the labeller function, I must specify the df to scale with. Tried instead with placing the dot instead of my_df, hoping that on each iteration ggplot would get the value of the df on any iteration:

```
labeller <- function(x) {
  paste0(x,"\n",  scales::dollar(sd(.$price) * x + mean(.$price)))
}

ex_df <- my_diamonds_split$Ideal
ex_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = scaled_log_price)) +
  geom_density() +
  scale_x_continuous(label = labeller, limits = c(-3, 3))
```

Returns:

> Error in is.data.frame(x) : object '.' not found

I then tried writing the function to accept an argument for the df to scale with:

```
labeller <- function(x, df) {
  paste0(x,"\n",  scales::dollar(sd(df$price) * x + mean(df$price)))
}

ex_df <- my_diamonds_split$Ideal
ex_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = scaled_log_price)) +
  geom_density() +
  scale_x_continuous(label = labeller(df = ex_df), limits = c(-3, 3)) # because when it comes to running in real life, I will try something like labeller(df = my_diamonds_split[[i]])
```

> Error in paste0(x, "\n", scales::dollar(sd(df$price) * x + mean(df$price))) :
> argument "x" is missing, with no default

Bearing in mind that the scaling must be done per iteration, how could I loop over my_diamonds_split, and on each iteration generate a ggplot per above?

```
labeller <- function(x) {
# how can I make df variable
  paste0(x,"\n",  scales::dollar(sd(df$price) * x + mean(df$price)))
}
for (i in split_names) {
  my_diamonds_split[[i]] %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = scaled_log_price)) +
    geom_density() +
    scale_x_continuous(label = labeller, # <--- here, labeller must be defined with df$price except that will difer on each iteration
                       limits = c(-3, 3))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a hacky way to get this result in facets. Basically, after converting to z scores, you add different amounts (say, multiples of 1000) to each group's z scores. Then you set all the breaks to this collection of points and label them with pre-calculated labels.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

f <- function(x) {
   y <- diamonds$price[diamonds$cut == x]
   paste(seq(-3, 3), scales::dollar(round(mean(y) + seq(-3, 3) * sd(y))), sep = "\n")
}

breaks <- as.vector(sapply(levels(diamonds$cut), f))

diamonds %>% 
    group_by(cut) %>% 
    mutate(z = scale(price) + 3 + 1000 * as.numeric(cut)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(z)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = z - 2, y = 1), alpha = 0) +
    geom_density() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks =  as.vector(sapply(1:5 * 1000, "+", 0:6)), 
                       labels = breaks) +
    facet_wrap(vars(cut), scales = "free_x") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6))
```

You would have to increase the plot size to make the dollar values more visible of course.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is really, really helpful. Thank you very much.